# Styling none actionbar-tabs

Tags: android, tabs, styles

In my application I'm using a mix of the actionbar tabs and the "old" TabWidget. I have no problems styling the actionbar tabs using a custom style theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
</style>
```

The TabWidgetStyle doesn't seem to have the same effect on the "old" TabWidget though. I've been trying to change the blue bottom tab-indicator color to red without any success. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this? Do I have to create an a separate tab class and use that as the tab indicator?

Thanks.